# random quote from array in external javascript not displaying onload

Tags: javascript

I'm a javascript beginner, and I'm trying to figure out why this code works when written in the head, but not when it's being referenced from an external file.

in the head of my html document, I'm referencing the javascript file "quote.js" as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="/js/quote.js"> </script>
```

the contents of quote.js are as follows

```
var textarray = [
    "Be Good.",
    "Our future depends powerfully on how well we understand the cosmos.",
    "Bottomless wonders spring from simple rules... repeated without end.",
    "All our science, measured against reality, is primitive and childlike — and yet, it is the most precious thing we have.",
    "To use violence is to already be defeated."
    ];

    function RndText() {
      var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
      document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
    }
    window.onload = function() { RndText(); }
```

finally, the div I'm replacing in the body is as follows...

```
<div id = "ShowText"></div>
```

it's probably a stupid mistake, but I've been trying to track it down for a while now, and I'm missing something.  When I write the contents of quote.js in my html head, it works fine.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the code works in the head, but not when included, it's likely to be a problem with the path to the script.  Double check that `/js/quote.js` is an appropriate location.  It may need to be `js/quote.js`, you you may have a typo.  In browsers like FireFox and Chrome, if you view the source code of your page you can click on the path to files like this and it loads the included file or shows you an error if the file is not found.

If you can share a link to the page, I can tell you with more certainty exactly what the problem is.

Also, you don't have to the language attribute if you're using XHTML, but that's not causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you :) It was indeed a stupid mistake.  I was referencing the file correctly, but I'd not updated my quote.js file to remove a <script type> tag I'd written there earlier.  I'd saved it, just not thrown it up on ftp.  Your suggestion to view the source code and investigate has given me a powerful new debugging tool that I should have figured out by now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code is running before the DOM is ready

Instead of `onload` use the event `DOMContentLoaded`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   //code here
}, false);
```